# Is there a way to change the default database for a giving model using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an application that only need a connection to one server. However, this server have 4 different databases that the app need to interact with.

Currently "the way I know how", I would have to create a new connection string in the `Web.Config` file for each database. Each connection will then have a separate context class which extends `DbContext`. Finally, each context will have a list of the model that represent each table.

I am hoping I can use one connection and one context. In order for me to do that, I would need somehow to point the models that are not part of the default database what database they belong to.

Is there a way to change the default database name for each model? I would prefer to use annotation  somehow to change it here is an example of that I am thinking.

```
[InitialCatalog("SecondaryDatabaseName")]
public class Site
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The database is specified in the connection string. There's no reason to hard-code it in the model itself - it would be similar to hard-coding the *server name*.

Comment: If you want the same context to connect to different databases just change its connection string

Comment: But if I do that and try to access a model without changing the connection string on the fly, I would get an error. if I hint the model what database it belongs too, then I wont have to worry about making a mistake. Maybe, instead of specifying the database name on the model class itself, I would do it in the context so it knows what database it should point too.

Comment: You should clarify what you want, *and* understand that what you call context and model are the same thing. *What* do you want? The same class to work with multiple DBs? Change the connection. Different contexts to work with different connections? Specify a different connection upon initialization by name

Comment: In other words `var myContext = new MyDbContext("MyConnectionName");`

Comment: by context I mean the class that extends `DbContext` class where I would list my `DbSet` (i.e. `public DbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; }`)`

Comment: Pass the connection name in the constructor.

Comment: I understand that I can do that. But if I mistakenly don't do that while trying to access a DbSet that does not belong to the default database I would get an error. For safety, either I would separate the DbSet into different context class or within the same context class I would tell the class where the DbSet should be pulled from

Comment: Then make a `ContextFactory` class that you always use to build the `Context`, make it require a string that selects a connection string by name from the config file, and returns a context created from that string.

Comment: Does this mean what I am looking for can't be done using Entity and .NET?

Comment: No, it just means you don't get it by default, because what you want isn't something that a lot of people would need.  You can easily build something to do what you want.

Comment: @Jaylen and when you deploy, you realize that the database uses a different name. Or you realize that in order to *test* your application you'll have to deploy to a testing database that's called `Test_MyDatabase". What do you mean `for safety`? If you want the tables to be separate, you could use schemas.

Comment: @Jaylen you haven't explained what you are looking for. Hard-coding the database name is a bug. You can hard-code the *connection* name by supplying your own parameterless constructor that uses a specific onnection name `MyContect():base("MyConnName"){}`.

Comment: I'm a little concerned about how you would handle `.Include` or LazyLoading between models that use different databases with your plan.